# Html.BeginForm FormMethod.Post is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to post my data to the action which is HttpPost. I always do it but this time I don't know what happens here. Submit button sends view data to Get action (I mean Detail action which is HttpGet) the button type is submit as you see and in the Html.BeginForm as you see I have used `FormMethod.Post` but just sends dar. I searched here but found nothing.

View:

```html
@using MF_Urmia.Models.ViewModels
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model CourseVm
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}
@using(Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Course", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CourseId)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-column">
        <h1 class="form-title-box">
         <span class="form-title">
                @ViewBag.title
            </span>
        </h1>

        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CourseName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CourseName, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TypeName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseTypeId)
                    .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CourseTypeList)
                    .OptionLabel("(Select One)")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "CourseType" }))
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "k-textbox", @type = "number"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Copacity)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Copacity, new { @class = "k-textbox", @type = "number" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TeacherName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TeacherName, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DurationTime)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DurationTime, new { @class = "k-textbox", @type = "number" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClassStart)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassStart, new { @class = "form-control kendo-date-picker", value = "", placeholder = "مثال :1396/05/20" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterLimit)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegisterLimit, new { @class = "form-control kendo-date-picker", value = "", placeholder = "مثال :1396/05/20" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label form-required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CourseImage)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field-2xl">
                @Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("ImageFile").Messages(m => m.Select("select")).Multiple(false)
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="frm-group">
            <div class="form-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
            </div>
            <div class="form-field full-width">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "k-textbox ck-editor-box" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <input value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-btn" />
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id)
{
    var courseId = id;
    using (var db = new MFUEntities())
    {
        var courseTypeList = db.CourseType.ToList();
        ViewBag.CourseTypeList = new SelectList(courseTypeList,
            nameof(CourseType.CourseTypeId), nameof(CourseType.DisplayName));

        if (courseId.HasValue)
        {
            //ويرايش
            ViewBag.title = "Edit";

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            //ثبت
            ViewBag.title = "Create";

            return View();
        }
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Detail(CourseVm vm)
{
    var courseId = vm.CourseId;
    using (var db = new MFUEntities())
    {
        if (courseId > 0)
        {
            //Edit
            var course = db.Course.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CourseId == vm.CourseId);
            if (course == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            //ويرايش عکس دوره
            var oldImage = course.CourseImage;
            //عکس قبلي را پاک کند
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Images/" + oldImage));
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Thumb/" + oldImage));

            vm.CourseImage = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") +
                         Path.GetExtension(vm.ImageFile.FileName);

            vm.ImageFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Images/" + vm.CourseImage));

            ImageResizer img = new ImageResizer();
            img.Resize(Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Images/" + vm.CourseImage),
                Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Thumb/" + vm.CourseImage));

            Mapper.Map(vm, course);
        }
        else
        {
            //Create
            //ثبت عکس دوره
            vm.CourseImage = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") +
                         Path.GetExtension(vm.ImageFile.FileName);

            vm.ImageFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Images/" + vm.CourseImage));

            ImageResizer img = new ImageResizer();
            img.Resize(Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Images/" + vm.CourseImage),
                Server.MapPath("/Images/CourseImage/Thumb/" + vm.CourseImage));

            var course = new Course();
            Mapper.Map(vm, course);

            course.Remained = vm.Copacity;
            course.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Course.Add(course);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. It should post to the HttpPost action method.

Comment: but it doesn't do it ... i really confused!!!:/

Comment: Check you do not have a `<form>` tag in your layout (a common cause is you have nested forms which is invalid html)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that was the problem ... i had a form tag in layout navbar